# Is the ON clause used in other places than with JOIN?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM Table JOIN Other ON Table.id = Other.tableId
```

I'm structuring a MySQL wrapper, and wondering if the "ON" keyword is used only in conjunction with joins (like above), or somewhere else as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ON` keyword is also found and can be in several other places, like **[`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)** and `ALTER TABLE` table statements (in the `FOREIGN KEY` definitions: `ON DELETE CASCADE`), in the **[`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)** syntax (`ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW`), in the **[`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)** statements, etc.

---

For joins, the **[`JOIN` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)** in the MySQL documentation has it all:

> MySQL supports the following `JOIN` syntaxes for the table_references part of `SELECT` statements and multiple-table `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements:

```
table_references:
    table_reference [, table_reference] ...

table_reference:
    table_factor
  | join_table

table_factor:
    tbl_name [[AS] alias] [index_hint_list]
  | table_subquery [AS] alias
  | ( table_references )
  | { OJ table_reference LEFT OUTER JOIN table_reference
        ON conditional_expr }

join_table:
    table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
  | table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor

join_condition:
    ON conditional_expr
  | USING (column_list)
```

So, `ON` can be used in `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements. It can be used with `JOIN`,  `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` (and the equivalent `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`).

Either `ON` or `USING` is to be used, not both.

It cannot be used with `NATURAL JOIN` (of course.)

And some differences from the ANSI/ISO SQL standard:

- you can use `ON` with `CROSS JOIN`.
- also (optionally) with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` (that's a MySQL addition)
- you can use `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` **without** `ON`.
- `UPDATE` and `DELETE` syntax has some differences with the standard, too.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use `ON` alone somewhere. its used only with `JOIN`s

but the joins you can use them without ON like that

```
   JOIN ... USING   //--according to SQL:2003
```

exemple:

```
a LEFT JOIN b USING (c1,c2,c3)
a LEFT JOIN b ON a.c1=b.c1 AND a.c2=b.c2 AND a.c3=b.c3
```

EDIT:

the `ON` clause could refer to columns in tables named to its right. the bellow example the `ON` clause can refer only to its operands.

Example:

```
  CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT);
  CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT);
  CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT);
  SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (i1 = i3) JOIN t3;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ON` *keyword* is also used in

- [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
- [`ON DELETE`/`ON UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)
- [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)
- [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)
- [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

Some of them are specific to MySQL.

Comment: You already have my +1. But `ON DELETE/UPDATE`, `CREATE TRIGGER`, and `GRANT` are standard SQL. And `CREATE INDEX` is used in SQL-Server, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's only present when using  `ANSI SQL-92 JOIN`. *Nothing else*.